# Eigenvalue formula

Tags: linear-algebra

So my book says that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $det (A- \lambda I) = 0$ but khan academy says that $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue iff $det (\lambda I - A ) = 0$.

Who is right? Both?

Comment: Both are right :)

Answer (score 6):

$\lambda I-A=(-I)\cdot(A-\lambda I)$ and $\det$ is multiplicative so
$$\det(\lambda I-A)=\det((-I)\cdot(A-\lambda I))=\det(-I)\cdot \det(A-\lambda I)=(-1)^n\cdot \det(A-\lambda I).$$

Answer (score 1):

Both are right!

$$\det(-B)=(-1)^n\det B$$

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are right since $$\det(A-\lambda I)=(-1)^n\det(\lambda I-A)$$.

Answer (score 0):

Both. Remember this equality $Av=\lambda v$. Here $\lambda$ is the Eigen value, $v$ the Eigen vector.